# I need to pass an id obtained from an api call to invoke another api call

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I need to pass an id obtained from an api call to invoke another api call, cant get it to work!
can anyone help?

The second api which will return and image call does not work and is greyed out in vs code
if anyone can help with an example, i would be greatful

```
currentResult: any;
  

     getData(){
       this.showLoading();
       const headers = {
         "x-api-key":'',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
        "x-requested-with": "xmlhttprequest",
        /* 'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.sygicBearerToken}` */
      }
        return this.http.get(
          this.ProxyUrl1+'https://api.sygictravelapi.com/1.2/en/places/list?parents=city:2&categories=discovering&limit=10', { headers: headers },
          )
        .pipe(tap (value => {
          this.loadingController.dismiss();
            console.log(value);
          }))
          
        
         this.http.get(
          this.ProxyUrl1+'https://api.sygictravelapi.com/1.2/en/places/{id}/media',{ headers: headers},)
        .pipe(tap (value => {
          this.loadingController.dismiss();
          console.log(value);
        })
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a return statement with the first this.http.get, anything after the return statement will not run, so it is grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

First: the second API call is greyed out because its written after a `return` call.

in order to call an additional API call using the result of the first call,
you can use RXJS `switchMap`
this will help you get a sequential requests, one after the other.

for exmaple example:

```
  get data() {
    return this.http.get('http://firstAPI').pipe(
      switchMap(id => this.http.get(`http://secondAPI/${id}`))
    );
  }
```

the first API call results "id" is passed to the second http call.

read more: [RXJS switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap)